# Android Tip,Tax,Total Calculator

Tags: java, android

Hello I am new too Java and learning how to built android apps.
I have this calculator that I have been working on I need help in figuring out how to set value to EditText. When user types in CA, OR, or FL in the EditText how would I assign the value to it?  CA = 7% , OR = 8% and FL = 10% thanks

```
public void calculate(View view) {

    EditText billET = findViewById(R.id.edit_bill_amount);
    EditText tipPercentET = findViewById(R.id.edit_tip_percent);
    EditText taxPercentET = findViewById(R.id.edit_tax_percent);


    String billString = billET.getText().toString();
    String tipPercentString = tipPercentET.getText().toString();
    String taxPercentString = taxPercentET.getText().toString();



    float bill = Float.parseFloat(billString);
    int tipPercent = Integer.parseInt(tipPercentString);
    int taxPercent = Integer.parseInt(taxPercentString);

    TipCalculator tc = new TipCalculator(tipPercent / 100.0F, bill, taxPercent / 100.0F);
    float taxAmount = tc.taxAmount();
    float tipAmount = tc.tipAmount();
    float total = tc.totalAmount();

    TextView taxAmountTV = findViewById(R.id.label_tax_amount_value);

    TextView tipAmountTV = findViewById(R.id.label_tip_amount_value);
    TextView totalAmountTV = findViewById(R.id.label_total_amount_value);

    taxAmountTV.setText(taxAmount + "");
    tipAmountTV.setText(tipAmount + "");
    totalAmountTV.setText(total + "");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **TextWatcher** for it.

```
TextWatcher watcher;
watcher=new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         edittext.removeTextChangedListener(watcher); 
         switch(s.toString){

            case "CA" : 
               edittext.setText("7%");
            case "OR" :
               edittext.setText("8%");
            case "FL" :
               edittext.setText("10%");
        }
        edittext.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    }
};
edittext.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementation would be something like this

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);

if (editText.getText().toString().equals("CA")) {
    textView.setText("CA=7%");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store those percentages to static variables and then assign them. If I'm getting your issue correctly a possible solution would be the following:

```
//outside of the calculate method

protected static String CA_PERCENTAGE = "CA = 7%";
protected static String OR_PERCENTAGE = "OR = 8%";
protected static String FL_PERCENTAGE = "FL = 10%";

//inside your calculate method
switch(area){

    case "CA" : 
        tipAmountTV.setText(CA_PERCENTAGE);
    case "OR" :
        tipAmountTV.setText(OR_PERCENTAGE);
    case "FL" :
        tipAmountTV.setText(FL_PERCENTAGE);
}
```

of course this is not the "prettiest" thing to do but since you're new to Java you get to play with the [switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).